# Replicate statements on secondary database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to propagate (certain) sql statements from a primary database to a secondary database in order to keep the data synced and testing purposes (the actual purpose).

My original idea via after insert/delete/update triggers on the tables of the primary database falls short due to the way errors can create doomed transactions. If the trigger propagating the statement to the secondary database fails, I may lose the statement writing to the primary database in the transaction. This is not acceptable as the primary database should remain (mostly) unaffected by anything happening to the secondary one. In case of failure an error log should be written in the primary database.

Is there a way to achieve this

- by using logic within the primary database
- and keeping aforementioned robustness against errors created when executing the statement on the secondary database?

Comment: Have a look at [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication), specifically transactional replication.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out "Always On" capabilities in SQL Server. Not sure if you can set the specific types of statements which get replicated but in effect it will create a replica of the primary database. And with Always On you can set the secondary replica to be read only if you want (vs. inaccessible).